ASP.NET Core Web API : an error occurred while sending the request. 400 Bad Request
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API with a POST method which takes JSON as request. Service only works if I send a specific string value. I sending content-type = json.
Note: if I send the status = NEW/QUEUE it works, but I send empty string it fails.
This fails - returns http 400 Bad Request - an error occurred while sending the request:
{
    "orderId": 0,
    "customerId": 999999,
    "orderNumber": "12345",
    "orderTypeId": 5,
    "status": ""
}

This works and returns http 200 Success:
{
    "orderId": 0,
    "customerId": 999999,
    "orderNumber": "12345",
    "orderTypeId": 5,
    "status": "**NEW**"
}

This also works and returns http 200 Success:
{
    "orderId": 0,
    "customerId": 999999,
    "orderNumber": "12345",
    "orderTypeId": 5,
    "status": "**QUEUE**"
}

Since the status is a string, it should allow empty values. Also there is no validation on the API side to stop it.
This should return 200 Success
{
    "orderId": 0,
    "customerId": 999999,
    "orderNumber": "12345",
    "orderTypeId": 5,
    "status": ""
}

    namespace Sample.DT
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Net;

    public class Orders
    {

        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Order number is required")]
        [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid order number")]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int OrderTypeId { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; } = "";

    }
}


This is an API that you built? We need to see the class that defines that json in order to see why it fails. If it is third party, then they should state that they require specific values in that property.

@jaabh API is inhouse built. Added the class. Please check

How does you r endpoint handle the requests that come in?

@jaabh It calls a controller method and if ModelState.IsValid it calls the DB. But in this case I don't it is even getting to the method.

I test class and the   "status": ""  in an asp.net core api template , then in controller post action  like:
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Uploadtest(Orders orders)
 {

     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     { return Ok(); }
    
     return BadRequest();
 }

result:


I agree @qing-quo but in my case I get 400 Bad Request!!
